# How to Handle Laravel error messages in vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I know I did something wrong here, but how do you handle error messages of Laravel in vue template?... is there a way of bypassing the @error of the laravel Blade templating

this is the vue component file (fileComponent.vue)

```
<template>

    <div class="row my-2">
    <div class="col-md-2 font-weight-bold pt-2">Grade:</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select name="grade" class="form-control @error('grade') is-invalid @enderror" v-model="selected_grade" @change="onChange($event)">
                
                <option v-for="grade in grading" :key="grade.id" :value="grade.name">{{grade.name}}</option>

            </select>
             @error('grade')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror

            <div class="row my-3" v-if="subjects !== null">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="card shadow">
                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">Subjects:</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" v-for="subject in subjects" :key="subject.id">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input @error('subjects') is-invalid @enderror" name="subjects[]" :id="subject.name" :value="subject.name"/> 
                                <label class="custom-control-label" :for="subject.name">{{subject.name}}</label>
                            </div>
                            @error('subjects')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

This is Shown on the page instead of error message
[image: This is shown instead of error message]

Comment: ` is there a way of bypassing the @error of the laravel Blade templating` , what do you mean by bypassing here

Comment: @bhucho... what I'm trying to say is that this '@error' tag is visible in the page, I don't get any error messages... so I was thinking is there any other way of displaying error messages from the backend in vue component?

Comment: you cant use blade syntax in Vue. Pass error bag from blade to Vue component and display.

Comment: @Mike Ross, How do you pass errors from blade to vue?... forgive me for asking dumb questions, I'm new to laravel + vue

Comment: <my-component :errors="{{ $errors }}"></my-component>